# Killing a Batch script from another

Tags: batch-file, kill-process

I have a script that will call other scripts to run then go back to process.
Example:
Call a script to ping and when it completes, go back to script.

My issue is I have a script called `Bounce.bat`

Here is the code:

```
@Echo off
set IPADDRESS=127.0.0.1
set INTERVAL=60

:PINGINTERVAL
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1
timeout %INTERVAL%
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

What I need is the command that will kill the `Bounce.bat` from inside another batch script.

I was going to try killing CMD but that kills the original script as well.

I Have tried experimenting as well as looking at script examples.

Does anyone know what is needed to kill this bat only?

Comment: You could use `title` to mark the doomed batch, then `taskkill` having found that batch's PID using `tasklist`.

Comment: I tried this taskkill /F /IM Bounce.bat and all it did was make the countdown flicker and continue. This usually kills other processes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Command "taskkill" to stop other processes in Windows.
You can write something like this in your other batch-file:
`taskkill /IM MYBATCHFILENAME.bat`
You can force to kill the process, if you are using the parameter /f at the end of your command.

Comment: That answer is nonsense as a batch file is never a running process. A batch file is just a script file which needs a script interpreter which is `cmd.exe`. For that reason there is never `MYBATCHFILENAME.bat` as image name in list of currently running tasks, but `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. There can be running multiple `cmd.exe` at the same time. Therefore the termination of the processing of a batch file requires the identification of which running `cmd.exe` is processing the batch file to terminate the right `cmd.exe`. The option `/f` of `taskkill` should be used best never.